# Does an access using the API count towards the user's consecutive days total?

Tags: discussion, users

Supposing I knock up a quick Python script that uses Py-StackExchange (or similar) to visit stackoverflow, retrieve a recent question, etc.; and then run a cron job to do this a couple of times a day... is this a quick way to upping my consecutive days visit count, or would the counter not be updated by the visits made via the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the API is not connected to your user account in any way, I don't see how it would...

Comment: + yes, the answer is 'no'.

Comment: OK, I saw a reference to StackAuth and assumed that was a way to authenticate yourself with StackApi.

Comment: @Vicky: StackAuth is way to find Stack Exchange sites and their corresponding API URLs (among a few other things). It's useful if you're building an app that works with all SE sites.